# How can we make gettimeofday function call fail in cygwin 1.7 environment using GDB?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, cygwin, time.h

I am looking for a way to fail the function call gettimeofday under cygwin 1.7 environment using GDB. Any one having any idea if we are using it in the below mentioned manner 
gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);

Thanks in advance
Aman

Answer (score 0):

You can set a breakpoint at the exit of the gettimeofday and modify the return code. Alternatively, a breakpoint can be set just before the call to gettimeofday, followed by modification of the calling parameter. There is not much you can do in the latter case though, except to modify the first argument to become NULL. This should make the libc implementation to return EFAULT (or crash, which I think cygwin implementation is more likely to do).

Comment: hi thank you for your reply but the problem is that gettimeofday is a system function defined in time.h and i am not able to step into its implementation code using break point in gdb, so i am not able to change calling parameters. If i change the first argument to NULL then i am getting Segmentation Fault. Do you know any way so that i can invalidate the current system date. Then i think this function will fail. Waiting for a reply from your side. @fork0

Comment: you can put a breakpoint on "system functions" (IOW, the functions you don't have source code to). Just give the name of function to breakpoint command

    br gettimeofday

Than you can use "stepi" to step instruction-by-instruction, or just give "step" to step until an instruction with line number is reached

Comment: You can modify the parameters gettimeofday will get by modifiying the stack directly: set *(unsigned long*)($sp - 4) = 0 (to crash), or modify the result, usually in EAX on x86: set $eax=-1

Comment: But if you can modify your code easily, you can just replace a call to  gettimeofday with something definitely broken: if ((gettimeofday(&now, NULL), (errno=EFAULT), -1) != 0) { ... }

Comment: and to answer your question about invalidating system time: no, you cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It was really helpful and i personally  appreciated your efforts. @fork0